# Post repeated when opening in overlay, how do I solve this?

Tags: php, css, templates, javascript

I created a code following the link example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_overlay_text

The problem that opens only the first post on all buttons. How do I solve this?

My code:

```
<style>
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
</style>
<?php /* Template Name: Equipe  */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'cpt_profissionais',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 9999,
    'paged' => $paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <button onclick="on()">Clique e saiba mais</button>
</div>

<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text"> <?php the_content(); ?></div>
</div>  

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>

<script>
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are using the same CSS id on all posts; it would need to be a specific CSS id per post with its specific CSS id referred to in the script

Comment: @Michael I figured it was this problem, how do I solve it? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

to be able to identify a specific "post" you need to have some unique attribute in its HTML. Usually the easiest thing to do is to use the post id as part of the `id` attribute (in your case maybe something like overlay{$post_id}). I personally started to prefer to use `data-` style attributes instead but for this use case the difference is more of esthetics than anything else.

Now that you have everything unique (and maybe even instead of doing that at all), either use a common class on all the "posts" and have a handler for click on elements with that class (easy with jQuery), or add a click handler on the containing `div` instead of the elements, and in the handler look at the event properties to find out which "post" was actually clicked.